Как скачивать потоковое видео на сторонних сайтах? JS
Есть сайт animego.org. Когда запускаешь видео то он отображается в потоковом видео. Через консоль ссылка на видео не дает результата.
Нужно скачать видео с сайта с помощью JS. Либо получить ссылки на потоковое видео что бы потом их скачать и объединить.
Скачивать не обязательно, просто подскажите пожалуйста как получить ссылки.

Подсказка: .mpd.

Это музыка, а мне нужно видео

Проблема заключается в том, что вы скорее всего не найдете прямую ссылку на видео материал, обычно их либо нет, либо они закрыты. Вам необходимо "прогрузить" видео полностью и склеить куски в единое целое. Насчёт готовых решений не подскажу, но суть заключается именно в таком подходе. Есть еще вариант скачивать куски на диск и потом их разом склеить, так будет более безопасно и при выходе скрипта из строя можно будет откатиться до последнего чанка.

@ДенисДавыдов, ты неправ. Это все потоки, в том числе несколько видео в разном качестве и аудио. Я легко могу скачать файл, но не хочу афишировать, как это сделать, поскольку такой подход применим на многих сайтах, а при желании его можно относительно легко закрыть.

@MoloF, да, объединять куски нужно, но вовсе не обязательно это делать руками.
